# Show whether my application can connect to internet or blocked by Firewall?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firewall, status, ping

In my application, i want to show the status of ( whether the connection is connected to internet ) by pinging to some ip address like google.com , and if there was responses, so the status is Online, and if not, i want to show the status Offline, and tell the user to configure his firewall.

How to ping using delphi, using for exemple a function to ping something like

```
  Ping(88.125.124.1);
```

a function which returns true if there are a connection or return false elsewhere.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of ping - which can be disabled on the target host - I would try to access a specific service/port, for example HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know that ping needs a timeOut. So you have a lot of solutions, my prefered is ICS openSource library with [TPing](http://wiki.overbyte.be/wiki/index.php/TPing)

Here is the demo code from François Piette :

```
unit OverbyteIcsPingTst1;

{$I OverbyteIcsDefs.inc}

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls, Controls,
  OverbyteIcsWndControl, OverbyteIcsPing;

const
  PingTestVersion    = 600;
  CopyRight : String = ' PingTest (c) 1997-2007 Francois Piette  V6.00 ';

type
  TPingTstForm = class(TForm)
    Ping1: TPing;
    Label1: TLabel;
    HostEdit: TEdit;
    PingButton: TButton;
    DisplayMemo: TMemo;
    CancelButton: TButton;
    procedure PingButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Ping1Display(Sender: TObject; Icmp: TObject; Msg: String);
    procedure Ping1DnsLookupDone(Sender: TObject; Error: Word);
    procedure CancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Ping1EchoRequest(Sender: TObject; Icmp: TObject);
    procedure Ping1EchoReply(Sender: TObject; Icmp: TObject; Status: Integer);
  end;

var
  PingTstForm: TPingTstForm;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TPingTstForm.PingButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DisplayMemo.Clear;
    DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Resolving host ''' + HostEdit.Text + '''');
    PingButton.Enabled   := FALSE;
    CancelButton.Enabled := TRUE;
    Ping1.DnsLookup(HostEdit.Text);
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TPingTstForm.Ping1DnsLookupDone(Sender: TObject; Error: Word);
begin
    CancelButton.Enabled := FALSE;
    PingButton.Enabled   := TRUE;

    if Error <> 0 then begin
        DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Unknown Host ''' + HostEdit.Text + '''');
        Exit;
    end;

    DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Host ''' + HostEdit.Text + ''' is ' + Ping1.DnsResult);
    Ping1.Address := Ping1.DnsResult;
    Ping1.Ping;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TPingTstForm.Ping1Display(Sender: TObject; Icmp: TObject; Msg: String);
begin
    DisplayMemo.Lines.Add(Msg);
end;



{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TPingTstForm.CancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Ping1.CancelDnsLookup;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TPingTstForm.Ping1EchoRequest(Sender: TObject; Icmp: TObject);
begin
    DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Sending ' + IntToStr(Ping1.Size) + ' bytes to ' +
                          Ping1.HostName + ' (' + Ping1.HostIP + ')');
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TPingTstForm.Ping1EchoReply(
    Sender : TObject;
    Icmp   : TObject;
    Status : Integer);
begin
    if Status <> 0 then
        { Success }
        DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Received ' + IntToStr(Ping1.Reply.DataSize) +
                              ' bytes from ' + Ping1.HostIP +
                              ' in ' + IntToStr(Ping1.Reply.RTT) + ' msecs')
    else
        { Failure }
        DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Cannot ping host (' + Ping1.HostIP + ') : ' +
                              Ping1.ErrorString +
                              '. Status = ' + IntToStr(Ping1.Reply.Status));
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}

end.
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use ICS, check the solution proposed by  Serhiy Perevoznyk here: http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa081503a.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). That's a whole different protocol running over IP (it's at the same layer of TCP and UDP, and a bunch of other protocols that uses IP). It can be blocked at any hop (for example at my company some routers don't route ICMP for security reasons), and it is not a good indicator if "connected to the Internet" for you means that HTTP works. You should try to get an HTTP answer from a known site. That's how for example Windows Vista/7 check if there is "internet access", they use a specific URL dedicated to that tasks. And in some setups ping may work, but HTTP could not, for example because there's a proxy needing authentication.